# Pause a matlab signal, perform calculations and continue the same signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am generating a time signal. Then after a certain time I would like to analyze the generated signal , calculate a new optimum value for `X` and apply the change in code and then continue generating the signal from where it left off with the new `X` value.

Just a very simplified code to generate a signal:

```
t = 0:0.1:100;
dt = t(2)-t(1);
A = 3;
Ohm = 1;
X = 5;

for ii = 1:length(t);
    S(ii)  = A*sin(Ohm*t(ii))+X;
end
```

In this code, for example I would like to analyze the signal at `t = 50` and then apply a new value to X and continue the signal.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The example you have allows you to create S without a loop:

```
 S=A*sin(Ohm*t)+X;
```

In other cases where you have a loop just let the loop run up to the point you want to use, in your case that would be

```
 for ii=1:50/dt
```

You might also want to use sections.
That way you can generate data in one section and have the analysis in another section.